# Run a function once per user for any endpoint in nodejs

Tags: node.js

My backend is written in NodeJS. I would like to push some real time data for my firestore database. My question how can i run a function once when a user is connected to my server. Also, this function will extract info from a cookie stored in the browser. I tried the singleton design pattern, but it is totally wrong because it runs for one user only.

Comment: Define what it means to be "connected" to your server. Since you mention endpoints I assume this is a webserver of some sort, which means you want to be tracking session. So you merely need to call a function when creating a new session for a user.

Comment: I am not using sessions. I am using cookies. What I mean by connected when a user submit a request to any end point to my nodejs webserver I want that function to run once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will involve storing some state per user (presumably you could do this in Firestore). As each user request comes in, you just need to check for said state and if it's not been set yet, invoke the function and set the state.

For example, here's how it might look if you were using [Express](https://expressjs.com/):

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // assume user is deserialized with state from store
  if (!req.user.hasRunFunc) {
    // run some function
    // update store setting 'hasRunFunc' state
  }
})
```

As long as the state is set, then subsequent requests from the same user would be skipped.

Comment: Is there is another solution that doesnot involve a database. I want it to be as fast as possible

Comment: @Ahmed I didn't use the term "database", I said "store" deliberately, this is your application so you can decide where the state is kept. If you are looking for a fast retrieval then perhaps you want to look at a persistent in-memory store like [Redis](https://redis.io/).

Comment: thanks james got it I was thinking along the same lines